# Better run time on CPU and can easily be modified to have GPU support

Tags: c++, gpu

I am relatively new to c++, and am currently working on some math application just to build my skills in c++.

I have two paradigm to adopt and i don't know which would be efficient on a CPU, and which would be easy to extend to have GPU support.

See code below:

```
/*
Background information:

MyDataArray<double> is a class that has a vector of data type double as a member. 
The vector length will be at least **20,000** (usually more).
I want to support operations (+,/,*,-, etc)
All operations listed above would be done element wise (over entire length)
e.g 

Question: Which of the two paradigm do you think would be
(1) more efficient on a CPU. 
(2) easy to extend to have GPU support (e.g CUDA C++)

*/
MyDataArray<double> T; 
MyDataArray<double> V;
MyDataArray<double> Q;
MyDataArray<double> D;
```

Paradigm 1: don't perform any operation but build an implicit graph.

```
/* 
OpsExpression<double> is just a class that keeps information about the 
operations involving objects of MyDataArray<double>. 
it stores it as an implicit graph of the operation. 
The implicit graph is then executed when the '.evaluate()' method is called.
 */

OpsExpression<double> exp_obj = T*V*(Q + D)*(V + T) ; //nothing executes. just builds an implicit graph of the operation. 

//... when the '.evaluate' method is called, exp_obj executes something 
// similar to the below:

double value;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    value = V.getValue(i) + T.getValue(i);
    value = (Q.getValue(i) + D.getValue(i)) * value;
    value = V.getValue(i) * value;
    value = T.getValue(i) * value;

    exp_obj.setValue(i,value);
}

// iterative scheme
for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 3000; iteration++)
{
    // ... do other similar operations 

    exp_obj.evaluate();

    // ... do other similar operations 
}
```

Paradigm 2: execute each operation.

```
/*
each operation is executed and the result is stored in a temporary MyDataArray<double> object.
*/

// iterative scheme 
for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 3000; iteration++ )
{
    //... do some other similar operations here 

    MyDataArray<double> tmp_v1 = V + T;
    MyDataArray<double> tmp_v2 = Q + D; 
    MyDataArray<double> tmp_v3 = tmp_v1 * tmp_v2; 
    MyDataArray<double> tmp_v4 = V * tmp_v3;
    MyDataArray<dobule> final_answer = T * tmp_v4;; 

    //...do some other similar operations here. 
}
```

The operations would be part of an iterative scheme in a numerical method. That means it would be called over and over again as the variables T, Q, V change each iteration.

I would really appreciate your help and any other way of approaching the problem.

Comment: Depending on how you write evaluate functions, paradigm number 1 should be the best both on Cpu and gpu as data most probably remain in registers.